# Como armazenar um Object no Firebase e utilizar no Ionic 3

Tags: javascript, json, ionic3, objetos

Quero armazenar os seguintes dados no Firebase e utilizar o mesmo no Ionic 3 porém não encontrei nenhuma documentação clara que possa me ajudar. Alguém pode me dar um caminho ?

Segue o código mostrando o Objeto dentro de meu `home.ts`

```
    initializeItems() {
    this.items = [
     {id: '1', nome:'Abaéte', rua:'Moacir', cidade:'Capão da Canoa', bairro:'Centro', numero:'396', ano:'1964', aptos:'55', adm:'Adsel', zelador:'Hugo', contato1:'(51) 0 0000 - 0000', contato2: '(51) 0000 - 0000', imagem:'assets/img/Abaete-min.jpg'},
  ];
```

E aqui um exemplo de meu App com a lista

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: é o database comum ou cloudstone?

Comment: Database comum.